# Why is this giving me an error ? count is

Tags: shell

```
ls>out
count="$(ls|wc -l)"
for i in {1..$count-2}
do
if[ "$(cat out|head -$count | tail -1)" != "rename.sh" ]; then
mv "$1$count$2" | cat out | head -$count | tail -1
fi
done
```

I really don't get why is not working...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you could explain what you are trying to achieve ? Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Didn't run the script yet, but perhaps you can put a space between "if" and left bracket "["

Comment: now is not giving me any error but is still not working it should rename all the files in a particular dir using the first parameter as root the second for the extension and a contor in the middle

Comment: Solved it!:)) tnx anyway

Comment: learn to use `set -x` to see what values are being set for your variables. Then you'll set some problems. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `ls` programatically anyhow -- certainly not to count files. See BashFAQ #4, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, why are you connecting `mv` to `cat` with a pipeline? `mv` doesn't write anything to stdout (thus, to that pipe), so it accomplishes nothing other than make the order of operations between that command and other pipeline element ambiguous (as all components of a pipeline are executed simultaneously).

Comment: Also, this is an *incredibly* inefficient way to iterate over files. Use the shell's built-in globbing facilities: `for file in *; do [ "$file" = rename.sh ] && continue; : "whatever else here"; done`. If you want to iterate over all but the last two, that's easy also: `files=( * ); for file in "${files[@]:0:${#files[@]} - 2}"; do ...; done`

Comment: You cannot use *brace-expansion* with a variable index, e.g. `{1..$count-2}` will not work (without a number of hacks). You are much better served with the suggestions above.

Answer (score -1):

```
    ls>out
count="$(ls|wc -l)"
for i in {1..$count-2}
do
if [ "$(cat out|head -$count | tail -1)" != "rename.sh" ]; then
mv "$1$count$2" | cat out | head -$count | tail -1
fi
done
```

put a space between if and '[' , the script will be work.

Comment: No, it won't -- there are other bugs. For instance, `for i in {1..$count-2}` isn't valid syntax to iterate over a numeric range.

Comment: I means the grammar is right, shell will execute the script and will not print out error.